# Does the kernel need to be the full automorphism group of the induced subgraph?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, permutations

Let $\Gamma$ be a simple graph. Suppose its automorphism group $G=\text{Aut}\Gamma$ is imprimitive on its vertex set $V$. Take a block system $\mathcal{B}$ of $V$. Let $B\in\mathcal B$, and let $K=G_{(\mathcal B)}$. If $K$ acts faithfully on the induced subgraph $[B]_\Gamma$, that is $K_{(B)}=1$, can we always say $K^B=\text{Aut}[B]_\Gamma$?

---

**NB**: $G_{(\mathcal B)}$ is the subgroup of $G$ which stabilises $\mathcal B$ pointwisely.

$G^\mathcal{B}:=G/G_{(\mathcal B)}$ is the group that acts on $\mathcal B$ faithfully.

The same way of definition applies to all other notations wherever it applies.

Comment: What is a block system? If it's just a $G$-invariant partition of $V$, then it shouldn't be difficult to find counterexamples to $G^B={\rm Aut}[B]_\Gamma$.

Comment: In your comment on my deleted answer you say $G$ acts transitively on $V$. Why isn't that stated in your question?

Comment: @anon, if you say a group acting imprimitive on the graph, then it implicitly means it is transitive.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I did not fully understand the definition.

Comment: What exactly is $G^B$? I would assume that $G^B = G_{\{B\}} / G_{(B)}$, where $G_{\{B\}}$ is the setwise stabizizer of $B$ and $G_{(B)}$ is the pointwise stabilizer. But then $G^B$ always acts faithfully on $B$ by definition. Or is $G^B$ itself the setwise stabilizer of $B$?

Comment: @DanShved, sorry, I have some mistake in my statement. I have amended it. $G^B$ is the induced permutation subgroup of $G$, that is $G^B=G/G_{(B)}$.

Comment: @Easy Again, I don't understand. How is $G/G_{(B)}$ a subgroup of $G$? My suggestion: include definitions for all the notation like $G_{(\mathcal{B})}$ and $K^B$ in your question. It is likely that people are refraining from posting an answer because they are not sure what the notation means. I know I am.

Comment: @DanShved, $G^B$ is not a subgroup of $G$, it is the induced permutation subgroup $G$ which acts on $B$ faithfully. I will update the formal definitions in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "no"; I offer one counterexample.

I assume that imprimitive means vertex transitive and imprimitive (an imprimitive group
need not be transitive).

Take $X$ to be the icosahedron, a 5-regular arc-transitive
graph on 12 vertices with automorphism group $G$ of order 120.
Now let $Y$ be the line graph of the subdivision graph of the icosahedron, i.e., 
put a new vertex in the middle of each of the 60 edges of the icosahedron, then take the line graph of this subdivided graph. 
Then $|V(Y)|=2|E(X)|=120$ and $H=\mathrm{Aut}(Y)$ is isomorphic to $G$ (by
theorems about automorphism groups of line graphs).
Since $G$ is arc transitive, $H$ is vertex transitive, in fact it acts regularly on the vertices of $Y$. Each vertex of $X$ gives rise to a clique 
of size five in $Y$, and these cliques are blocks of imprimitivity for $H$. The subgroup of $H$ that fixes one of these cliques has order at most five, and so it does not induce the full automorphism group of the clique.

I am sure this construction will work with many other arc-transitive graphs.